# How to understand why a reciever cannot hear, see or catch waves of all frequencies at the same time

Tags: education

I am explaining about how antennas work to my son. Like, how antennas need to be set for certain frequencies or wavelength. As an example, i provide the example of eyes and ears as receivers and how they are limited to see/hear between particular limits of frequency/wavelength. 
However I myself had mugged it up, while i was student, and have no idea why it happens like that.

So, how in a simple language, I can understand, why a receiver is only able to catch certain signals ?

Comment: I am no expert, but it seems you are asking how a radio tuner works, with a fixed antenna lenght? Is that it?

Comment: You are working with a false assumption. From a basic physics point of view one can build receivers of arbitrary bandwidth, it was, until lately, just not a technically necessary and economical thing to do so. Ultra-wideband radios may change that in the future.

Comment: It's not true that a receiver "catch[es]" only certain signals. The antenna gain varies with wavelength.  Maybe you can start by showing your son resonant behavior in piano (or guitar) strings.